# Is it possible to export unit testcase reports as any document form from Android studio?

Tags: android, unit-testing

> I have written some unit test cases for my app and its working fine,Now I need the reports as a document whether it is possible to export directly from Android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're using the new [unit test feature](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support): 
Run them from the command line with

```
gradle test
```

or

```
gradlew test
```

and you'll receive the report in `html` format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,gradlew test command results Build successful now where should i check for the html doc,i could not find anything new in build folder!

Comment: Oh, it probably only shows when a test fails. Let a test fail and itll show you the path to the html file. It also produces a report when all test pass, but it doesnt show the path in the command line.

Comment: :) I found it in the project folder app\build\outputs\reports\androidTests\connected there it is all the html